# Inbound email being bounced back from Google Apps for your Domain: 550

Tags: domain-name-system, email, g-suite, gmail

I have a simple cpanel-administered www hosting account (wherebarney.com), and for well over a year I've used Google Apps for your Domain to handle the email, using gmail.

Recently the majority of (but not all) inbound mail has been bounced back to the sender with 'Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client'.

I can find lots of advice about how to secure my domain to stop spoofing etc, but AFAICT this only affects outbound mail and spam, not inbound mail.

What else should I look at?

(reason: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. )

```
----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to wheresbarney.com.:
DATA
<<< 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. 
<<< 550-mx0a-00082601.pphosted.com [67.231.145.42]:48701 is not permitted to relay
<<< 550 through this server without authentication.
550 5.1.1 <barn@wheresbarney.com>... User unknown
<<< 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
<<< 503-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. 
<<< 503-mx0a-00082601.pphosted.com [67.231.145.42]:48701 is not permitted to relay
<<< 503-through this server without authentication.
<<< 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by cleaning up the MX entries for my domain. I had records for google.com servers (correct), and some for my domain (incorrect). Deleting those for my domain, leaving only the google servers, fixed this.

*Before*

```
Priority    Points to
0   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
0   WHERESBARNEY.COM.
5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
10  ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
100 CLUSTER1.CUSTOMWEBHOST.COM.
100 CLUSTER2.CUSTOMWEBHOST.COM.
```

*After*

```
Priority    Points to
0   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
10  ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

Note - the google apps admin console checks your MX records, and reported my previous configuration as correct.

Comment: That would be "Technically Correct."  However, as you found out, not quite functional.